# Convert Local time to UTC with timezoneoffset in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a local date/timestamp and I have a timezone offset stored in String format (***myStringTimeStamp*** variable name below). I need to convert the local date/timestamp to UTC time.

The format the timestamp is in is: **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**

I have tried variations on:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

//Convert timestamp to date 
Date d = sdf.parse(myStringTimeStamp, new ParsePosition(0)); 

newTimeStamp = sdf.format(d);
```

But I can't seem to figure out the right formula. Any help?

I can't use 3rd party libraries/frameworks.

Comment: If at all possible, use the `java.time` package (in Java 8), or the Joda-Time library (in Java 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to be because you're setting the target timezone before parsing.

First parse, then set timezone, and finally format.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

//Convert timestamp to date 
Date d = sdf.parse(myStringTimeStamp, new ParsePosition(0)); 

sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

newTimeStamp = sdf.format(d);
```

Comment: Something so SIMPLE! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

    //Convert timestamp to date 
    Date d = sdf.parse(myStringTimeStamp, new ParsePosition(0)); 

    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    newTimeStamp = sdf.format(d);
```